# Перенос строки выравнивается по центру с флексом

Tags: html, css

Как можно в коде ниже сделать перенос строки без центрирования, начиная с левой стороны?

```css
.whiteButton__atm{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100px
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: 'Inter Medium';
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
<button class="whiteButton__atm"> <p>Пополнить счет что-то еще</p></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так?

```css
.whiteButton__atm {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100px border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: 'Inter Medium';
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.whiteButton__atm p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="whiteButton__atm"> <p>Пополнить счет что-то еще</p></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.whiteButton__atm{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100px
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: 'Inter Medium';
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
<button class="whiteButton__atm"> <p>Пополнить счет что-то еще</p></button>
```